# Pointcut to extended class methods with Aspectj

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, aop, aspectj, spring-aop

I have the following dependency added to my pom.xml

```
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.aspectj/aspectjweaver -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.5</version>
        </dependency>
```

I had an controller that extends an abstract controller

```
// actual controller
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/testContoller/v1")
class TestController: AbstractTestController()


// abstract class
abstract class AbstractTestController {
    @GetMapping("/test")
    fun testFunction():String {
        return "hello"
    } 
}
```

The aspect class

```
@Aspect
@Configuration
class TestAspect {
    @Around(
        "execution(* com.test.project.controllers.TestController.*(..) )"
    )
    fun testIntercept(joinPoint: ProceedingJoinPoint): Any? {
        return joinPoint.proceed()
    }
}
```

Now, I want to create a pointcut to all of the method executions on `AbstractTestContoller` via `TestController`. How do I do it?

I've tried:

```
"execution(* com.test.project.controllers.TestController.*(..) )"
"execution(* com.test.project.controllers.TestController+.*(..) )"
"execution(* com.test.project.controllers.AbstractTestController.*(..) )"
"execution(* com.test.project.controllers.AbstractTestController+.*(..) )"


"within(com.test.project.controllers.TestController)"
"within(com.test.project.controllers.TestController+)"
"within(com.test.project.controllers.AbstractTestController)"
"within(com.test.project.controllers.AbstractTestController+)"
```

None of these work

Comment: How is your project structure ? Please confirm if the `Aspect` is auto-detected by the component scan

Answer (score 1):

#### AspectJ

Adding the AspectJ weaver to your Maven project has zero effect if you do not also do one of the following:

- add AspectJ Maven plugin in order to actually make the AspectJ compiler weave your aspects in to the target classes OR
- run Java with the AspectJ weaving agent like `-javaagent:/my/path/aspectjweaver.jar`.

#### Spring AOP

Second possibility: You are not really using AspectJ as you may believe you do but simply an "AOP lite" framework called Spring AOP, which is configured in a completely different way. So unless you provide a full [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in your updated question or in a GitHub project, nobody will be able to tell you exactly what you did wrong.

Whether you use AspectJ or Spring AOP, in both cases I suggest you read some documentation first.

**Update:** Your `@Aspect` for Spring AOP should be a `@Component`, not a `@Configuration`. Please put the latter into a separate class and actually also configure something there.